# SFTP remote readdir Failure - national characters in file name

Tags: ubuntu, sftp, locale, character-encoding

I have created a directory with national characters in it's name. I can see and browse this directory via `ssh`

```
# cd /root
# ls
СтранноеРусскоеИмя
```

but can't do it via `SFTP`:

```
sftp> cd /root
sftp> ls
remote readdir("/root"): Failure
sftp>
```

Why and how to fix?

---

Client software is innocent, because it can work with other hosts.

---

Permissions are also OK, because if filenames are English, `ls` works ok.

[image]

on this screenshot you can see two subsequent `ls` commands in `root` directory. First one was failed while second one succeeded. The only difference is that national charactered name file was deleted in parallel `ssh` session.

Comment: I think ssh use shell and env of remote host and sftp use shell and env of local host.

Comment: How to check/fix?

Comment: Did you log in through `sftp` as root on the remote system? If not, the account simply won't have permission to read root's directory.

Comment: It can read, if all filenames are English

Comment: I think this might be related to the users `profile` that is attempting to login via `sftp`. This is true on all my BSD servers, anyway.

Comment: what specific problem with `profile` do you mean?

Comment: You can try with -o SetEnv and this way set your locale. Don't forget man sftp.

Answer (score 1):

This is unlikely to be anything to do with the locale. Based on a throwaway mention in one of your comments that, "*this might be related to the user's profile that is attempting to login via `sftp`*", I would hazard that you are not logging in to the remote server as root.

Non-root users cannot access `/root`, and this is reflected in your `sftp` session. Here is an identical one on a local server of mine, with a file named `СтранноеРусскоеИмя` already placed into the directory `/tmp/526629`:

```
sftp remoteuser@remoteserver
Connected to remoteserver.
sftp> cd /root
sftp> ls
remote readdir("/root"): Permission denied
sftp> cd /tmp/526629
sftp> ls
СтранноеРусскоеИмя
sftp>
```

Another option might indeed be locale. Here in this session we have the same server configuration as before:

```
# Locale is UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8" sftp remoteuser@remoteserver
Connected to remoteserver.
sftp> cd /tmp/526629/
sftp> ls
СтранноеРусскоеИмя
sftp>

# Locale is C
LC_CTYPE=C sftp remoteuser@remoteserver
Connected to remoteserver.
sftp> cd /tmp/526629/
sftp> ls

sftp>
```

I can't reproduce your `remote readdir("/root"): Failure`, but maybe you could check the locale on the remote server to ensure that it is set to a UTF-8 variant.

Comment: If I was not able to access `/root` I would not be able to list non-russian names also, but I can. I can provide a screenshot if it convince you.

Comment: @Dims, when I talk about `/root` this is the home directory for the `root` user. It's not `/`, the root of the filesystem.

Comment: sure, see the screenshot please

Comment: Also note, that my error message is not "Permission denied", but "Failure"

Comment: @Dims the updated question is very helpful. I've got another scenario in my answer that demonstrates a locale issue. It may help. (Or it may not.)